# Error in x[seq_len(xlen - n)] - R - sorted bar chart

Tags: r, ggplot2, gganimate

I am tableau dev, but I found myself in place, where I can't do sorting bar animation in that program. I am sorry if this will be really beginner question. 
I am trying to reproduce code from [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54926358/animated-sorted-bar-chart-problem-with-overlapping-bars) but I am getting error:

> Error in x[seq_len(xlen - n)] :    object of type 'closure' is not
>   subsettable

Could you help me find what I am doing wrong?

```
library(tidyverse)
library(gganimate)
theme_set(theme_classic())

df <- data.frame(Player = rep(c("Aguero", "Salah", "Aubameyang", "Kane"), 6), 
             Team = rep(c("ManCity", "Liverpool", "Arsenal", "Tottenham"), 6), 
             Gameday = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,6,6,6,6),
             Goals = c(0,1,2,0,1,1,3,1,2,1,3,2,2,2,4,3,3,2,4,5,5,3,5,6),
             stringsAsFactors = F)
gap <- df %>%

# for each player, note his the rank from his previous day
group_by(Player) %>%
arrange(Gameday) %>%
mutate(prev.rank = lag(rank)) %>%
ungroup() %>%

# for every game day,
# sort players by rank & break ties by previous day's rank
group_by(Gameday) %>%
arrange(rank, prev.rank) %>%
mutate(x = seq(1, n())) %>%
ungroup() %>%

ggplot(aes(x = x, y = Goals, fill = Player, color = Player)) +
# geom_tile(aes(y = Goals/2, height = Goals, width = width)) +
geom_col() +
geom_text(aes(y = 0, label = Player), hjust = 1) +
geom_text(aes(label = Value_lbl), hjust = 0) +

# rest of the code below is unchanged from the question
coord_flip(clip = "off", expand = FALSE) +
scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::comma) +
scale_x_reverse() +
guides(color = FALSE, fill = FALSE) +
labs(title = "Gameday {closest_state}", x="", y = "Goals scored") +
theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0, size = 22),
    axis.ticks.y = element_blank(), 
    axis.text.y  = element_blank(),
    plot.margin = margin(1,1,1,4, "cm")) +
transition_states(Gameday, transition_length = 4, state_length = 1) +
ease_aes('cubic-in-out')
```

Comment: Your ggplot call has no data argument. Try ggplot(gap, aes(..

Comment: No, he is piping ion the data

Comment: The problem occurs here: `mutate(prev.rank = lag(rank))`. There is no column `rank` in your data, so `dplyr` uses the *function*  `rank` from `base` and this is clearly not subsettable as the error message suggests.